# Why _ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO is not defined, despite having ARMv8 processor?

Tags: c, aes, simd, arm64

I've been trying to implement hardware accelerated AES in C/C++, on a device that has an ARMv8 processor. I checked `cpuinfo` by running `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and it shows that AES feature is supported.

But unfortunately when I compile my application it outputs an error that says `vaeseq_u8` and other related functions for AES are undefined. I checked the source code for `<arm_neon.h>` and found that, those functions are only defined if `__ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO` is enabled.

I also discovered that `__aarch64__` is also **not** defined, but CPU info says that I am using AArch64 !

I tried to forcefully enable crypto feature by doing  `#define _ARM_FEATURE_CRYPTO 1`. But then Clang returns error messages like:

```
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: intrinsic %llvm.arm.neon.aesmc
clang-5.0: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 5.0.2 (tags/RELEASE_502/final)
Target: armv7a--linux-android19
```

I am using Clang compiler, my environment is Android. I am using Cxxdroid to compile and run this. 
Why is the **target** in the error message : `armv7a--linux-android19` ?

I really dont know what is going wrong... !?

Every help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you set abifilter in the gradle file?

Comment: Oops. You aren't using Android Studio. Did you set the build  target to `arm64-a`?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Yes, I tried, but I get this error message ```unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible with this triple.'
1 error generated.``` ?